# Reset git lfs repository to pointers

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a [git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com) repository checked out. All the binaries are *pointers*. I pulled the real binaries with:

```bash
git lfs pull --include some/binaries
```

I used the binaries and now I would like to "unpull" the binaries and convert them to the pointers again, so I can reclaim the disk space.

I didn't find any suitable command to do that, and mangling with `.git/lfs/objects` plus hard resets make me nervous.

Question: How to convert the tracked binaries back to pointers?

Edit:

- I just found an open feature request for that:
  ["Add command to undo fetch and checkout"](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1189)

Comment: Have you tried modifying `.gitattributes` file? Check this: https://rehansaeed.com/gitattributes-best-practices/#git-large-file-system-lfs

Answer (score 16):

An open LFS issue suggested to run

```
git read-tree HEAD && GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git checkout -f HEAD
```

Note from the [issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/951#issuecomment-581477084):

> If you run that in a dirty working tree, you'll blow away your changes, so don't do that.

Running this worked for me even when using LFS inside a submodule.

Answer (score 12):

As you mentioned it's not been implemented yet in git LFS. Git LFS users are using scripts to achieve the same functionality. Here's one that works taken from your link.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

lfs_files=($(git lfs ls-files -n))
for file in "${lfs_files[@]}"; do        
    git cat-file -e "HEAD:${file}" && git cat-file -p "HEAD:${file}" > "$file"
done
    
rm -rf .git/lfs/objects
```

It simply creates a list of all files returned by `git lfs ls-files` and iterates through it to replace the file by its pointer. The last line deletes all git LFS objects from the local repository.

Comment: After doing this, `git status` shows all of those files as modified.

Answer (score 0):

It converts files back to pointers.
Just like undo `git lfs pull`.
:-)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# ref: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1189#issuecomment-348013275
# ref: https://sabicalija.github.io/git-lfs-intro/

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No input: quit."
    exit 1
fi

cur_size=$(du -sh . | awk -F " " '{print $1}')
for bfile in $@; do
    # to pointer
    # print file size
    f_size=$(du -sh $bfile | awk -F " " '{print $1}')
    mv $bfile $bfile.bak
    cat $bfile.bak | git lfs clean > $bfile
    rm $bfile.bak
    pt_size=$(du -h $bfile | awk -F " " '{print $1}')
    printf "%-30s: " $bfile
    printf "%s" $f_size
    printf " -> %s \n" $pt_size

    # delete cache in .git
    hash_value=$(cat $bfile | grep oid | cut -d ":" -f 2)
    cache_path=$(find . | grep $hash_value)
    if [ -z ${cache_path} ];then
        printf "#WARNING# oid can't find in cache: %s \n" $hash_value
    else
        rm $cache_path
        printf ">> Pruned cache at: %s \n" $cache_path
        git checkout -- $bfile
    fi
done

# report result
after_size=$(du -sh . | awk -F " " '{print $1}')
printf "Finish: Current directory size shrink"
printf "(%s" $cur_size
printf " -> %s).\n" $after_size
exit 0
```