# Can I "undo" `git lfs checkout?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I ran the following commands

```
git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.pdf"
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git push origin master
```

The I end up with local files with 1 kB only. I learned that I need an additional

```
git lfs checkout
```

to get "the real files back" and I just wonder, whether there is some command to hide the huge files again, that is some "undo `git lfs checkout`"?

Concerning `git lfs prune`: This does not change anything:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Original files are present, then

```
$ git lfs prune
* 36 local objects, 29 retained
Pruning 7 files, (935 KB)
* Deleted 7 files

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Files still present...

Comment: try git-lfs-prune

Comment: @JohnnyWiller No, original files are still there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset git lfs repository to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377619/reset-git-lfs-repository-to-pointers)

Comment: @Drarig29 Thank you for your useful link. I'll check next time.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this myself. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 24 Oct. 2022, *you can't.* No `git lfs uncheckout` command exists *yet*.

As a work-around, maybe just delete the whole repo and re-clone it. WARNING: make sure you've committed all local changes and safely pushed them to the remote *before* deleting your repo locally, however, or else *you permanently lose those changes!*

There is an open issue for a feature request for this, however, here: [Add command to undo fetch and checkout](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1189#issue-151659746). Please go there and upvote it and leave a comment to get it some love ❤️. That feature request has been open since *early 2016.*

Comment: OK :-) As my question was more out of curiosity and not a real use case: what is the use case for "uncheckout"?

Comment: @Christoph, to save memory. I work in a repo that is 250 GB in size--nearly all of it being from `git lfs`. My code modules use _zero_ of those `git lfs` files! I'd like to uncheckout them since I'm not even using them to build my code! It's a mono-repo. Other code needs them.

Answer (score 0):

What about `rm -f $(git lfs ls-files -n) && git checkout HEAD -- $(git lfs ls-files -n) && git lfs prune -f`?

- `git lfs ls-files -n` => get list of known LFS files
- `rm -f` => remove checked-out files
- `git checkout HEAD` => reset file(s) to being pointers
- `git lfs prune -f` => clean unreferenced LFS objects